# How can I get lat/lon from an address?

Tags: 7, location

I have these modules

```
addressfield
geofield
geocoder
```

Is there any function to which I can pass an address like `Stree, zipcode city, Country` and it returns a lat/lon from that address?

I have searched in the code of geofield and geocoder but unable to find any helper function.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using google geocoding with geocoder module, you may use another geocoding provider, i think this requires a google map token now given google's new rules :

```
// @return Geometry Returns a geoPHP geometry object. Generally a Point.
$point = geocoder('google', $address);
$lat = $point->coords[1];
$lon = $point->coords[0];
```

I did this long time ago, please check.